# hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method

Tags: debian, time-synchronization, clock-synchronization

On a Debian server, I'm having problem with `hwclock`:

```
$ hwclock --show 
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --debug option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

System runs on backports kernel `Debian 4.9.18-1~bpo8+1 (2017-04-10)`.

Here's debug output:

```
$ hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux 2.25.2
hwclock: cannot open /dev/rtc: Device or resource busy
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

clocksource:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
tsc
```

Finally, `rtc` device exists:

```
$ ls -l /dev/rtc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Apr 29 16:41 /dev/rtc -> rtc0
crw------- 1 root root 253, 0 Apr 29 16:41 /dev/rtc0
```

Comment: Have you tried running these commands as root/via sudo?

Comment: @PaulHaldane Yes, of course. I have 3 identical servers, only on one of them `hwclock` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be connected to `clocksource`, check `available_clocksource`:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
tsc hpet acpi_pm
```

Based on [answer to "What does “clocksource tsc unstable” mean?"](https://superuser.com/questions/393969/what-does-clocksource-tsc-unstable-mean) it looks like [TSC (Time Stamp Counter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is not very reliable.

By updating `/etc/default/grub` you can switch to another available clocksource. I'm using [HPET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer).

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="clocksource=hpet"
```

and updating grub:

```
update-grub2
```

After reboot `hwclock` works again (just reboot without any modification might have helped as well - it might be just question for how long).

**NOTE**: Optimal clocksource might depend on your motherboard and CPU model.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the fix was just to type "sudo" before the command, as the "can't access" actually means it doesn't have perms to access /dev/rtcX. Running it with sudo fixed it by giving it root perms.
Your solution would be just to run `sudo hwclock --show` instead of `hwclock --show`

Answer (score -3):

run on a virtual machine.

su - //afswitch root.run hwclock

Comment: This needs more explanation.